# Ingress cannot resolve NodePort IP in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have an ingress defined as:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: zaz-address
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: foo-bar-com

spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /zaz/*
        backend:
          serviceName: zaz-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Then the service `zap-service` is a `nodeport` defined as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zaz-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.27.255.88
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32455
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: zap
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

The `nodeport` is successfully selecting the two pods behind it serving my service. I can see in the `GKE` services list that the `nodeport` has an IP that looks internal.

When I check in the same interface the `ingress`, it also looks all fine, but serving zero pods.

When I describe the `ingress` on the other hand I can see:

```
Rules:
  Host                                    Path  Backends
  ----                                    ----  --------
  foo.bar.com
                                          /zaz/*   zaz-service:8080 (<none>)
```

Which looks like the `ingress` is unable to resolve the service `IP`. What am I doing wrong here? I cannot access the service through the external domain name, I am getting an error `404`.

How can I make the ingress translate the domain name `zaz-service` into the proper `IP` so it can redirect traffic there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was, as expected, not reading the documentation thoroughly.

The port stated in the `Ingress` path is not a "forwarding" mechanism but a "filtering" one.  In my head it made sense that it would be redirecting `http(s)` traffic to port `8080`, which is the one where the `Service` behind was listening to, and the `Pod` behind the service too.

Reality was that it would not route traffic which was not port `8080` to the service.  To make it cleaner I changed the port in the `Ingress` from `8080` to `80` and in the `Service` the front-facing port from `8080` to `80` too.

Now all requests coming from the internet can reach the server successfully.

Comment: I would recommend posting this type of questions in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) as StackOverflow is for Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the wildcards in the path are [not supported yet](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41881).
Any reason why not using just the following in your case?

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /zaz
        backend:
          serviceName: zaz-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: Tried this too, unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Do you get a response from a default backend when going to `<your-url>/some-random-path`? (edit - I see you do).
Is the app server doing any redirects? If the app server is not aware of the fact that it doesn't run at the root endpoint, it makes redirects with leaving `/zaz` out. Not sure if that is your case.

Comment: Also this might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54274992/k8s-ingress-rule-for-multiple-paths-in-same-backend-service?rq=1

Comment: The app is expecting traffic on `/`, should I change it to expect `zaz/`?

Comment: Either you make the app expect the traffic on `/zaz` or you apply the `rewrite-target` annotation and set the `rewrite-target` to `/`: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite

Also, are you able to tell from the logs if the 404 is being returned by the default ingress backend?